# np.expm1 doesn't return desired value

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm currently trying the following concept:

1. I applied ‍`np.log1p()` to the independent variables and dependent variable (price)
2. Assuming `X = independent` variables and `Y = dependent` variable, I train_test_split X & Y
3. Then I trained the `LinearRegression()`, `Ridge()`, `Lasso()`, and `ElasticNet()` models

Given that the labels I used to train the model were also `log1p(Y)`, I'm assuming the model predictions are also log values?

If the predictions are log values, how come `np.expm1` doesn't return a value that is on a similar scale?

Linear Regression Code for reference

```
import os
import glob
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import re
from scipy.stats import skew
from scipy import stats
from scipy.stats import norm
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score, train_test_split, GridSearchCV, ShuffleSplit
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

df_num = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df_cat = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,2,size=(10000, 2)), columns=['cat1', 'cat2'])
price = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(10000, 1)), columns=['price'])

y = price

skewness = df_num.apply(lambda x: skew(x))
skewness = skewness[abs(skewness) > 0.5]
skewed_features = skewness.index
df_num[skewed_features] = np.log1p(df_num[skewed_features])

y = np.log1p(y)

train = pd.concat([df_num, df_cat], axis = 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train, y, test_size = 0.3, random_state = 0)

lr_clf = LinearRegression()
lr_clf.fit(X_train, y_train)

def predict_price(A, B, C, D, cat1):
  cat1_index = np.where(train.columns == cat1)[0][0]
  
  x = np.zeros(len(train.columns))
  x[0] = np.log1p(A)
  x[1] = np.log1p(B)
  x[2] = np.log1p(C)
  x[3] = np.log1p(D)

  if cat1_index >= 0:
    x[cat1_index] = 1

  return  np.expm1(lr_clf.predict([x])[0])

predict_price(20, 30, 15, 55, 'cat2')
```

***EDIT1:*** I tried to recreate an example from scratch, but I can't seem to replicate the issue I'm running into. The issue I run into in my real data is that:

- predictions work totally fine if I DON'T log-normalize inputs when training and DON'T log normalize inputs when predicting.
- HOWEVER when I do log-normalize when training and log normalize inputs and np.expm1 the prediction, the value is totally off.

Please let me know if there is anything I can explain more clearly.

Comment: Please post a [mre] (emphasis on *minimal* required to demonstrate the issue); you could use some dummy or toy data for this. SO does not work by simply throwing all our code here as is.

Comment: Btw you might consider using [TransformedTargetRegressor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.TransformedTargetRegressor.html) for target data

Comment: @desertnaut Thanks for the response, I tried to recreate toy data, but it doesn't seem to replicate the issue I'm encountering.

Comment: That's a great step toward resolving the issue yourself.

Comment: Is it possible that after applying np.log1p, the inputs are still skewed, and hence causes the prediction to be off?

Comment: @amiola thanks for the response! How does TransformedTargetRegressor differ from directly using np.log1p on the target?